# How to delete from a sharepoint List?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

Hello i got a sharepoint list with 7972 items and i want to delete all the Items in the list. First i tried it with the rest api and had no success. So i try it with the javascript stuff from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx.

This is my Code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var siteUrl = "/test/testfiles";
    var listName = "Error Documentation";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var scriptbase = "www.example.at";
        $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.Runtime.js", function () {
            $.getScript(scriptbase + "SP.js", doNext);
        });
    });

    function doNext()
    {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        spList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

        //The Caml-Query
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Controller" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorCode" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorText" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorDescription" /></ViewFields><RowLimit>10000</RowLimit></View>');

        //get all Items from the list
        var collListItem = spList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(collListItem);

        //Execute the query
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();
            for (var i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                var oListItem = collListItem.itemAt(i);
                oListItem.deleteObject();
            };

            //Final Delete order
            clientContext.executeQueryAsync();
        });

    }

</script>
```

Acording to the Debugger from the internet explorer everything runs without any errors. Even the last `clientContext.executeQueryAsync();` gets called but on the sharepoint list nothing changes.

So any advise or help would be great and thanks for your time.

**Edit**: here is the exception i get: `Sys.ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range. Parameter name: serverRelativeUrlOrFullUrl`

**Edit2:** Here is the now working Code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var siteUrl = "/knowledge/lzpowerbase";
    var listName = "Error Documentation";

    $(document).ready(function () {
        ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(doNext, "SP.Runtime.js");
        });

    function doNext() {
        var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
        spList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listName);

        //The Caml-Query
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml('<View><ViewFields><FieldRef Name="Controller" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorCode" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorText" /><FieldRef Name="ErrorDescription" /></ViewFields><RowLimit>10000</RowLimit></View>');

        //get all Items from the list
        var collListItem = spList.getItems(camlQuery);

        clientContext.load(collListItem);

        //Execute the query
        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () {

            var itemCount = collListItem.get_count();
            for (var i = itemCount - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                this.oListItem = collListItem.itemAt(i);
                this.oListItem.deleteObject();

                //Final Delete order
                clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function () { console.log('success'); },
                function (args) { console.log(args.get_message()); });

            };


        });

    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that your request (delete 8000 items) is too large. Try moving the executeQueryAsync(); in the for-loop. This will cause some performance slowdown but if that works, you might be able to modify the script to delete the items in batches of 500 or something.

Also, to get a clear error, add the success and failure handlers in your executeQueryAsync call like:

```
clientContext.executeQueryAsync(function(){ console.log('success');},
function(args){console.log(args.get_message();});
```

Comment: thanks for the tipp with the clientContext in the loop it works even with the 8000 items. Just very slow.

Comment: Well, to speed it up you could hold keep count with a variable and just execute the executeQueryAsync for example every 200 items were deleted. In any case it would speed up.

Answer (score 1):

One more thing: You might want to use the SharePoint functions for waiting for scripts instead that scriptbase stuff:

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(doNext, "SP.Runtime.js");
//or
_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames.push("doNext");
```

Comment: why? is the scriptbase stuff bad? is there something i dont know?

Comment: no, it's not really bad. But you don't need it! Usually on a SharePoint Site these resources are loaded automatically (it just takes a while, that's why you have to wait until they are initialized).